# Hide HTML element with PHP

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have this code to get me a datatable of users:

users.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        getUsers();
    });
</script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="kt-portlet">
          <div class="kt-portlet__body">
              <?php if(count($autores)>0):?>
              <table class="table table-striped- table-hover" id="users">
                <thead class="thead-light">
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Username</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tBody">
                    
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <?php else: ?>
              <?php getAlertMsg("1"); ?>
              <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

function getUsers(); :

```
function getUsers() {
    $('#tBody').html('');
    $.ajax({            
        type : 'POST',
        url  : './index.php?action=users-get',
        success :  function(data) {
            $('#tBody').append(data);
            $('#users').DataTable( {
                dom: "<'row'<'col-md-4'B><'col-md-4'f><'col-md-4'p>>" +
                       "<'row'<'col-md-6'><'col-md-6'>>" +
                       "<'row'<'col-md-12't>><'row'<'col-md-4'l><'col-md-4'i><'col-md-4'p>>",
                buttons: [
                     {
                         extend: 'collection',
                         text: '<i class="la la-download"></i> Export',
                         autoClose: true,
                         className: 'btn btn-success btn-icon-sm btn-square dropdown-toggle',
                         buttons: [
                                     { text: '<i class="fas fa-copy"></i>\xa0\xa0  Copy', extend: 'copyHtml5'},
                                     { text: '<i class="fas fa-file-excel"></i>\xa0\xa0  Excel', extend: 'excelHtml5'},
                                     { text: '<i class="fas fa-file-csv"></i>\xa0\xa0  CSV', extend: 'csvHtml5'},
                                     { text: '<i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i>\xa0\xa0  PDF', extend: 'pdfHtml5'},
                                     { text: '<i class="fas fa-print"></i>\xa0\xa0  Print', extend: 'print' }
                                  ],
                              fade: true,
                     }
                  ],
                pageLength: 25,
                processing: true,
                responsive: true
            } );
        },
        complete: function(){
           setTimeout(function() {
           }, 15000);    
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

users-get page:

```
<?php
$a = new SQLMan();
$a->tablename = "users_users";
$autores= $a->select("","",$where=" hidden = 0");

foreach($autores as $autor):?>
<tr class="<?php getLastItems($autor->fields["created_at"]); ?>">
    <td class="pull-right"><span class="kt-media kt-media--circle kt-media--success kt-margin-r-5 kt-margin-t-5"><span><?php $nom = $autor->fields['name']; $ape = $autor->fields['last_name'] ;  echo $nom[0];  if ($ape != "") { echo $ape[0]; } ?></span></span></td>
    <td><?php echo $autor->fields["user_name"];?></td>
    <td><a class='kt-link kt-font-bold' href='<?php setURL(); ?>./user/<?php echo $autor->fields["user_name"]; ?>'><?php echo $autor->fields["name"]; if($autor->fields["last_name"] != "") { echo " " . $autor->fields["last_name"] ;};?></a></td>
    <td><a class='kt-link kt-font-bold' href='mailto:<?php echo $autor->fields["email"]; ?>'><?php echo $autor->fields["email"];?></a></td>
    <td><?php if ($autor->fields["is_active"] == "1") { echo "<span class='kt-badge kt-badge--success  kt-badge--inline kt-badge--pill'>Active</span>"; } elseif ($autor->fields["is_active"] == "0") { echo "<span class='kt-badge kt-badge--danger kt-badge--inline kt-badge--pill'>Deactivated</span>"; } ?></td>
    <td>
        <a href="<?php setURL(); ?>./user/<?php echo $autor->fields["id"]; ?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon btn-icon-md" title="View User">
            <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>                       
        </a>
        <a href="<?php setURL(); ?>./user/<?php echo $autor->fields["id"]; ?>#edit-book" class="btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon btn-icon-md" title="Edit User">                          
            <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>                       
        </a>
        <a href="./index.php?action=user-del&id=<?php echo $autor->fields["id"]; ?>" id="btn" class="btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon btn-icon-md btn-book-del" title="Delete Book">                          
            <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>                       
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Now I've set up roles and I want to hide the button edit if the PHP variable $users_perms is set to 1. As it's generated from AJAX, If I add to the users_get page an IF to hide/show html if $users_perms == 1, it won't work since that page doesn't have the $users_perms variable defined (it's defined in users.php).

How can I send the $users_perms variable to users-get page to hide the edit button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your user.php, you can store the variable to your javascript function like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    getUsers('<?php echo $yourVariableUsers_perms ?>');
});
```

On javascript function like this

```
function getUsers(var) {
$('#tBody').html('');
$.ajax({            
    type : 'POST',
    url  : './index.php?action=users-get',
    data : {'var' : var},
    success :  function(data) {
        $('#tBody').append(data);
        $('#users').DataTable( {
            dom: "<'row'<'col-md-4'B><'col-md-4'f><'col-md-4'p>>" +
                   "<'row'<'col-md-6'><'col-md-6'>>" +
                   "<'row'<'col-md-12't>><'row'<'col-md-4'l><'col-md-4'i><'col-md-4'p>>",
            buttons: [
                 {
                     extend: 'collection',
                     text: '<i class="la la-download"></i> Export',
                     autoClose: true,
                     className: 'btn btn-success btn-icon-sm btn-square dropdown-toggle',
                     buttons: [
                                 { text: '<i class="fas fa-copy"></i>\xa0\xa0  Copy', extend: 'copyHtml5'},
                                 { text: '<i class="fas fa-file-excel"></i>\xa0\xa0  Excel', extend: 'excelHtml5'},
                                 { text: '<i class="fas fa-file-csv"></i>\xa0\xa0  CSV', extend: 'csvHtml5'},
                                 { text: '<i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i>\xa0\xa0  PDF', extend: 'pdfHtml5'},
                                 { text: '<i class="fas fa-print"></i>\xa0\xa0  Print', extend: 'print' }
                              ],
                          fade: true,
                 }
              ],
            pageLength: 25,
            processing: true,
            responsive: true
        } );
    },
    complete: function(){
       setTimeout(function() {
       }, 15000);    
    }
});
return false;}
```

And Now you can get your php variable in users-get page like this

```
$users_perms = $_POST['var'];
```